# Azure maps resets when screen orientation change

Tags: java, android, azure-maps

So im developing a geolocalization app, and when my user is navigating the map, in AZURE MAPS, whenever he change the orientation of the screen it resets, and i want to prevent that from happening, is there anyway i can achieve that ?
Im using android studio with java.
Ive read some things about beeing possible in OnReady, but i cant figure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android's default for orientation change is to reset the activity, this isn't an Azure Maps specific thing. You can modify this behavior in your manifest. In the  tag, you can add `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`, this will stop the activity from reloading and call `onConfigurationChanged()` instead when the orientation is changed or the keyboard is hidden.